# render page using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function I created, and it is actually woking quite nicely:

```
   const successPage = () => { 

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if(user) {
    
      console.log("calling success page : " + user.uid)


        firestore.collection("profiledata").doc(user.uid).update({
            accountStatus: "active"
        }).then (() => {
            this.props.history.push(routes.LANDING)
        })
    
  }
  })
}
```

problem is, when I try to do this:

```
.then (() => {
            this.props.history.push(routes.LANDING)
        })
```

it returns this error: `successPage(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.`

how to do I fix this?

Comment: can you include the component that handles the ``LANDING`` route

Comment: @سعيد I added what Daniel said below and it worked, but I now see another error. please see my comment below!

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your successPage.js ? from what it looks your just forgot to add a return before your jsx.

For example:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  *return* <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right, I added that and it worked... but now I am running into the problem that it won't actually render that page still (routes.LANDING). I tried to do `window.open(routes.LANDING)`, but it opened a new window In chrome. how do I get it to just go to another page?

Comment: are you using "react-router-dom" ?